# Maxent Probabilities Values

Tags: qgis, distribution, maxent, results, species

I am working on my first experiment with Maxent.

I am using two different species.

When I receive the output map and look at it in QGIS the values for suitable habitat probability do not sum to 1.

Rather, they each sum to much less or much more.

[image]

[image]

These are the two scales that are produced. Is this abnormal? Does it simply reflect that the model is not very confident? What could explain this?

Comment: are you sure you are looking at the right output? it looks like you have the standard deviation map rather than the mean projection?